# How to make all packages visible to Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I am making a Maven application using Spring boot framework. I am also using Hibernate ORM technology to persist objects into a database via Postgres. A problem I am encountering is the `Unknown entity: ca.mcgill.ecse321.model.Vehicle` error because Hibernate is unable to "see" that class. The snippet below shows my class hierarchy and my pom.xml file. Is there a way to make Hibernate look for the model classes?
I am not using a hibernate.cfg.xml file.

[Class hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFilR.png)

**Pom.xml**

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>RideSharing-backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>RideSharing</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things:

1. You can remove Hibernate dependency from pom as JPA as by default Hibernate dependency in it. So remove below:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. If you have your main class in root package here `ca.mcgill.ecse321` then `@SpringBootApplication` will auto configure your entities.
3. If you don't have your main class in root package then in your main class then scan entities by annotation to put your package name:

   ```
   @EntityScan("ca.mcgill.ecse321.model")
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class MyApplication {

   }
   ```